Set class based on currently focused item jQuery
Got a nav element with some dynamically generated anchor links and some corresponding divs. Currently, I have it set up to where clicking on a link in the nav sets its class to "active" and sets focus on the target, which works great. The problem is that a keyboard user or mobile user can also tab or swipe to the next div, so I want to set the active nav link class on target focus, not on click. How do I go about doing that?
Relevant script:
    $('.carousel nav ul li').each(function(i, e) {
        $(this).wrapInner($('<a>', {
            "href": "#" + "slide-" + i
        }));
    });

    $(".carousel .content .section").each(function(i, e) {
        $(this).attr("id", "slide-" + i).addClass("collapsed").attr("tabindex","0");
    });

    $(".carousel nav ul li a").eq(0).addClass("active");
   
    $(".carousel nav a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(".carousel nav a.active").removeClass("active"); 
        $(this).addClass("active"); 
        var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
        target.focus();
    });

Sample rendered HTML:
<div class="carousel">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#slide-0" class="active">web development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#slide-1">graphic design</a></li>
      <li>test service</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="section expanded" id="slide-0" tabindex="0">
      <h2>Web Development</h2>
      <p>Description of web development services.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section collapsed" id="slide-1" tabindex="0">
      <h2>Graphic Design</h2>
      <p>Description of graphic design services.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section collapsed" id="slide-2" tabindex="0">
      <h2>Test Service</h2>
      <p>Description of graphic design services.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


"mobile user can also tab": just to be sure, do you mean tab or tap? If tab, then I don't think it will be user-friendly when you change the focus with target.focus() -- this interferes with the natural tab-order, and users cannot just tab from one nav item to the next.

Use .on("focus", function...) instead of .click(function...)

@barmar no, that would make it so when the person is focused on the nav link it would change it to "active", not when focus is set on the section.

@trincot - no, I mean tab, as in pressing your tab key. That is how people with disabilities who can't use a mouse interact with web pages

@DeanH, that's what I understood. Did you read the rest of my comment expanding on that tab use?

@trincot all your comment says is "Use .on("focus", function...) instead of .click(function...) – Barmar" so it looks like truncated the comment and I can't see the full response. If you submit an answer, I should be able to read the whole thing.

That is not my comment you are quoting.

@trincot sorry about that. I have no idea what you mean about it "interferes with the natural tab order". You should be able to tab to the next section when you are focused on one.

Yes, that is true, but you are changing focus with the .focus method. Sorry, but maybe it is just your question that I don't understand. I will leave this for someone else who might get what you are after.

@trincot - steps to replicate: click the second link in the nav bar. It will set focus on the second div, set the class to expanded and set the class of the link to active. Now press your tab key. It will set focus on the third div. When it does, I want it to change the active class on the second link to the third one.

You should be able to use .on("focus") but put the event handler on the divs rather than the anchors. E.g. $("#content div.section").on("focus", function...)

I think what @trincot was getting at is that you do target.focus() in the event handler. If you do that in a handler for the focus event it will be weird because you'll tab to one place and then set focus to somewhere else. Although I think in your desired case target is actually the place they're tabbing to, so it's a no-op.

You can achieve this by handling the focus event on the content divs, and have the handler set the active class on the corresponding navigation item.
As you'll set the active class there, you can remove the similar code from your current click handler. The code to change could look like this:
$(".carousel nav a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    target.focus();
});


$("[id^=slide-]").on("focus", function () {
    $(".carousel nav a.active").removeClass("active"); 
    $(`.carousel nav a[href="#${this.id}"]`).addClass("active"); 
});


Brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks much.
